# react native 'unexpected url' error

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, axios, expo

I'm using axios to post data to my local server.

```
    _handleBarCodeRead = data => {
    axios.post('192.168.0.100/getitem', {
        id: data.data,

      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

data get posted on event

```
       <BarCodeScanner
          torchMode="off"
          onBarCodeRead={this._handleBarCodeRead}

        />
```

I get an error 'unexpeted url 192.168.0.100/getitem'
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make the url either relative `('/getitem')` or *properly* absolute by prefixing it (with http or https) `'http://192.168.0.100/getitem'`.

```js
    _handleBarCodeRead = data => {
axios.post('http://192.168.0.100/getitem', {
    id: data.data,

  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

};

Comment: Thank you. The problem was not adding the http.